# Inequality to prove $2\le(a^x)+(1/(a^x))$ for $a\ge 1;x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

How to prove $2\le(a^x)+(1/(a^x))$ for $a\ge 1; x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. If $a = 3$ and $x = 0$ then we get $3 \leq 2$. The best I can do is $a^{x} + \frac{1}{a^{x}} \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note

$$a^x+\frac1{a^x}
= \left( a^{x/2} - \frac1{a^{x/2}}\right)^2 +2\ge 2$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
I would define $f(a) = a^x + a^{-x}$, find the minimum point $a^*$ and show that $f(a^*) \ge a$